# Cocoa bindings to display NSDictionary keys in NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, binding

I currently have a NSArrayController whose content property is (programmatically) set to an NSMutableDictionary and my UI has a single NSTableView.  The information that the NSMutableDictionary contains is not set via the UI.

How would I use Cocoa bindings to display the dictionary keys in NSTableView?  I already know how to use the DataSource methods, I just want to know how to use bindings for this.

Comment: I don't see how that makes sense.  It would be common to have an array controller associated with an array whose *members* are dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it makes sense to set an array controller's content to an `NSMutableDictionary`. Rather, you should bind the array controller to the dictionary's `allKeys` property. Or consider using an `NSDictionaryController`, which was designed specifically for this purpose.